# Rails - text_field class with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to give a text_field class on a condition. Is there a way to do it in rails?

I.e.

```
<%= text_field 'person', 'employer', :tabindex => 5,:style => 'width: 50%;', :class => 'required' %>
```

I need the class to be "required" only if a certain, condition occurs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use ternary (`condition ? then : else`) operator:

```
<%= text_field 'person', 'employer', :tabindex => 5,:style => 'width: 50%;', 
               :class => (condition ? 'required': '') %>
```

It's not easy to read, but solves your problem. Alternatively you can set a variable to the requred class name before using it in the link:

```
<% class = 'required' if condition %>
<%= text_field 'person', 'employer', :tabindex => 5,:style => 'width: 50%;', 
               :class => class %>
```

Comment: hmm won't the second version complain that class is not defined if `condition` is not met?

Comment: In theory ruby would assign a `nil` value to the variable. The only requirement for this to have an assignment for that variable somewhere (even after the first usage), AFAIK. But of course it can be initialized to empty string somewhere.

Comment: If the 2nd example (`class= ... if condition`) is done in a loop, once the value is set will it continue for subsequent iterations?

Comment: @justintime: in this case you need to reset the `class` variable, otherwise it will be stuck to `'required'`.

Answer (score 4):

In general in rails you can do something like

```
<% if condition %>
  <%= text_field 'person', 'employer', :tabindex => 5,:style => 'width: 50%;', :class => 'required' %>
<% else %>
  <%= text_field 'person', 'employer', :tabindex => 5,:style => 'width: 50%;' %>
<% end %>
```

Still your case is a bit more simple so you can do the check in place:

```
  <%= text_field 'person', 'employer', :tabindex => 5,:style => 'width: 50%;', :class => condition ? 'required' : nil %>
```

This will result in class being nil if condition is not met and 'required' otherwise.